# Referential equality issue with Nullable Integer

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

As per the official documentation [KotlinLang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation), Nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) are boxed.

boxedA === anotherBoxedA evaluates to true if and only if boxedA and anotherBoxedA point to the same object

```
val a: Int = 10000
println(a === a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

> But if I just change the value of a to 80, the Referential equality becomes true!!

```
val a: Int = 80
println(a === a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'true'!!!
```

How can it point differently just by the change of value?